# ¿Cómo obtener todas las propiedades de un objeto seleccionado de un ListView, Android Xamarin?

Tags: android-listview, xamarin.android

```
private void LstCatalogos_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
                {
                  var list = e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                  Toast.MakeText(this, list.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
```

Sólo puedo sacar el nombre que viene en el item del listview, pero lo que yo quiero, es que cuando seleccione el Item, me traiga Todo el Objeto que lo compone, (IdBaseDatos, Campo1, Campo2, etc)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo necesito , porque tengo que Actualizar el item del listview, y es necesario el IdBaseDatos, para poder hacerlo

De ésta manera hice mi adapter para llenar el ListView

```
 public void InicializarList()
    {
        //Se carga el ListView
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        var tblProveedor = db.Table<Color>().Where(x => x.Borrado == false).OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);

        ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

        foreach (var prove in tblProveedor)
        {
            lst.Add(prove.Nombre);
        }
        string[] arr = (String[])lst.ToArray(typeof(string));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arr);
        lstCatalogos.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo creas con un Adapter entonces, en el metodo `GetView()`, con la propiedad `View#Tag` lo puedes lograr, asignado el objeto actual de la lista:

```
public View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   //..

   convertView = cargarVistaParaLista(getContext);
   convertView.Tag = collecciondeObjetos.ElementAt(position);

   //..
   //..
  return convertView;
}
```

Entonces en el evento para obtener el Tag utilizas la propiedad `View#Tag` y lo conviertes al tipo de dato correspondiente:

```
private void LstCatalogos_ItemLongClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
{
                  var list = e.Parent.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                  var referenciaObjeto = (TipoObjeto)e.View.Tag;
                  init idBaseDeDatos = referenciaObjeto.IdBaseDatos;
                  Toast.MakeText(this, list.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```